# Python code to get a folder structure along with size

Tags: python, csv

Hi I have two blocks of code as below -

```
def GetHumanReadable(size,precision=2):
    suffixes=['B','KB','MB','GB','TB']
    suffixIndex = 0
    while size > 1024:
        suffixIndex += 1 #increment the index of the suffix
        size = size/1024.0 #apply the division
    return "%.*f %d"%(precision,size,suffixes[suffixIndex])

import os
def list_files(startpath):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
        level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
        indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
        print('{}{}/'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
        subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
        for f in sorted(files, key=lambda f: os.path.getsize(root + os.sep + f)):
            converted_size = GetHumanReadable(os.path.getsize(root + os.sep + f))
            print('{}{} - {}B'.format(subindent, f, converted_size))
```

I get the following error when I execute the following -

```
list_files(r'C:\Users\Downloads')
```

Error - TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Need a good solution for this. I am mainly looking to get folder/sub-folder along with sizes. The above code currently give size for each file. Modification requested to give size for the folder/subfolders itself. In the end need to write the output in a csv file. Thanks

PS: I dont own any of the above code. All code has been taken from stackoverflow and other similar platforms and then combined.

Comment: `suffixes` is a list of strings. Therefore, you have to change `%d` to `%s` in `GetHumanReadable` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change %d to %s and remove the B from the end of the print statement in `list_files`:

```
In [227]: def GetHumanReadable(size,precision=2):
     ...:     suffixes=['B','KB','MB','GB','TB']
     ...:     suffixIndex = 0
     ...:     while size > 1024:
     ...:         suffixIndex += 1 #increment the index of the suffix
     ...:         size = size/1024.0 #apply the division
     ...:     return "%.*f %s"%(precision,size,suffixes[suffixIndex])
     ...: 
     ...: import os
     ...: def list_files(startpath):
     ...:     for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
     ...:         level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
     ...:         indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
     ...:         print('{}{}/'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
     ...:         subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
     ...:         for f in sorted(files, key=lambda f: os.path.getsize(root + os.sep + f)):
     ...:             converted_size = GetHumanReadable(os.path.getsize(root + os.sep + f))
     ...:             print('{}{} - {}'.format(subindent, f, converted_size))
     ...: list_files(r'E:\Downloads\test')
test/
    file2.py - 40.00 B
    chap4exercise3.py - 57.00 B
    file1.py - 60.00 B
    run.py - 95.00 B
    largerfile.pdf - 767.08 KB
    __pycache__/
        file1.cpython-36.pyc - 239.00 B
        chap4exercise3.cpython-36.pyc - 253.00 B
```

Comment: Thanks Works fine. Can you also help me in writing all this data into a csv file in a format which is easily readable and understandable? Showing folder size, subfolder size and then file size. Really appreciate your help here. Thanks!

Comment: csv definitely isn't the best way to store nested data. I'd probably use `json` or `xml`.

Comment: Well, not very well versed with XML or JSON. Do you have a code for that which I can check. Will really appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because, your suffixes[suffixIndex] is a string that holds 'KB' string!
so changing

```
return "%.*f %d"%(precision,size,suffixes[suffixIndex])
```

to

```
return "%.*f %s"%(precision,size,suffixes[suffixIndex])
```

will get the desired output!

To writer the data to file as:

```
def list_files(startpath):
    with open('output.txt','w') as file:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
            level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
            indent = ' ,' * 4 * (level)
            file.write('{}{}/\n'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
            subindent = ' ,' * 4 * (level + 1)
            for f in sorted(files, key=lambda f: os.path.getsize(root + os.sep + f)):
                converted_size = GetHumanReadable(os.path.getsize(root + os.sep + f))
                file.write('{}{},{}\n'.format(subindent, f, converted_size))
```

Comment: Thanks all. Works fine.

Comment: Glad that it helped! I've added the edits for writer the contents to csv!

Comment: That gives the output in a text file. I saved the text file as a CSV but there is no indentation. :/

Comment: that was a typo! If you want with indentations, you can just write your string to file separated by `,` and I' edited the answer for the same

Comment: My Bad, All good. But I believe JSON and XML is going to be a better approach for this kind of data as mentioned in the comments above. Does that change a lot of the code logic?